# Postgres data type integer[] in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

ruby : ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

```
@user = User.find(1)
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, first_name: "d", last_name: "g", crypted_password: "$2a$10$h4Bil49Pw.bxf0jXvw4mEeYzKh2tgL9kUx/CtBeTg2HB...", salt: "3r3xXr3oqHGP5MpzdxAE", in_games: nil>
```

I am loading a user as shown above. The data type for in_games in postrges is integer[] 
I do not understand why I am receiving an error. (shown below)

```
 if @user.in_games.nil?
    array = []
    @user.in_games = array.push(@game.id)
  else
    @user.in_games << @game.id
  end
 @user.save


ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
LINE 1: UPDATE "users" SET "in_games" = '---
                                    ^
: UPDATE "users" SET "in_games" = '---
```

Comment: Typically, you'll want this in a separate table rather than in an int array. Arrays are a convenience type for pl functions and complicated queries, and are occasionally useful to cache nested data (or derived types like tsvectors), but they're really not meant to be used as a table replacement -- which is what you seem to be doing. As things are, each in_games update will generate a dead tuple in your table. This is not so good because you may end up with disk page splits -- turning your table into a giant Swiss cheese instead of a tight cluster on user IDs. (See the table fillfactor option.)

Comment: Thank you for the input Denis, I will definitely remove this after reading your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're abandoning your array approach but I'll leave some notes here for posterity.

---

Rails3 doesn't understand PostgreSQL's array types out of the box (AFAIK this is remedied in Rails4), you'll need to include the [`postgres_ext`](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) or similar gem to make PostgreSQL arrays work with Rails3.

Without something to support arrays, ActiveRecord will try to YAMLize any input it doesn't understand, hence the odd looking string:

```
UPDATE "users" SET "in_games" = '---
                                ^^^^
```

that ends up in your SQL. If you look at the whole SQL statement you should see a YAML version of your array.

---

As an aside, once you get array support working, this won't work the way you expect it to:

```
@user.in_games << @game.id
```

The `postgres_ext` docs have this to say:

> The following will modify the default value of the names attribute.
>
> ```
> a = Item.new
> a.names << 'foo'
>
> b = Item.new
> puts b.names
> # => ['foo']
> ```
>
> The supported way of modifying `a.names`:
>
> ```
> a = Item.new
> a.names += ['foo']
>
> b = Item.new
> puts b.names
> # => []
> ```
>
> As a result, in place operators are discouraged and will not be
>   supported in postgres_ext at this time.

If you say `@user.in_games << @game.id` then you're modifying `in_games` in-place and ActiveRecord won't notice that anything has changed, if you assign it a whole new array:

```
@user.in_games += [ @game.id ]
# equivalent to @user.in_games = @user.in_games + [ @game.id ]
```

then ActiveRecord will notice that `in_games` has changed and everything (`_changed?` methods, the SQL UPDATE, ...) should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. It would have taken me much longer to wrap my head around this.